# File Doesn't Work in Virtual Server

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP file called `footer10.php` that worked just fine in shared hosting.  I moved it to a virtual server and it no longer works.

I get these errors  when I pull the file up in a browser:

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /var/www/.../...com/httpdocs/.../footer10.php on line 23

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /var/www/.../...com/httpdocs/.../footer10.php on line 23
Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

This is on line 23 of the file:

```
$presult = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM submission") or die(mysql_error());
```

Any idea what I need to do to make the file work on the virtual server?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Did you connected to database host? Post the related code also

Comment: check make sure the apache user has access to the db and the database is in the localhost

Comment: @ Anush Prem how do I see if the Apache user has access to the database?

Answer (score 2):

The error message means that PHP could not connect to the MySQL database.

If you're establishing the connection on your own using `mysql_connect` you should make sure that host, user and password are correct (according to the error message no password was specified)

The user name and the empty password makes me think you've relied on the `mysql.default_*` settings on your old server. You can specify a default server in your php.ini, refer to the [manual](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.default-host) for this. The connection will then be opened automatically by php.

So what you have to do is to find out correct credentials for your MySQL server. Then you either establish a connection using `mysql_connect`/`mysql_pconnect` or add it to the php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO) , what does this line mean ?
It means you need to update you're mysql connection settings with the correct ones ( username , password and host ) by this i mean you're mysql connection settings on the new server are different than the ones on the old server . Then make shure to move the database from one server to another .